# Python Map Function

Tags: python, dijkstra

I need some help with Python's map function. I am trying to execute this code, though I get an error:

**Updated Post**

This is my exact code, along with the outputs of each function:

```
infinity = 1000000
invalid_node = -1
startNode = 0

#Values to assign to each node
class Node:
     def __init__(self):
       self.distFromSource = infinity
       self.previous = invalid_node
       self.visited = False

#read in all network nodes
#node = the distance values between nodes
def network():
    f = open ('network.txt', 'r')
    theNetwork = [[int(networkNode) for networkNode in line.split(',')] for line in f.readlines()]
    #theNetwork = [[int(node) for node in line.split(',')] for line in f.readlines()]
    print theNetwork

    return theNetwork

#for each node assign default values
#populate table with default values
def populateNodeTable(): 
    nodeTable = []
    index = 0
    f = open('network.txt', 'r')
    for line in f: 
      networkNode = map(int, line.split(',')) 
      nodeTable.append(Node())

      print "The previous node is " ,nodeTable[index].previous 
      print "The distance from source is " ,nodeTable[index].distFromSource
      #print networkNode
      index +=1
    nodeTable[startNode].distFromSource = 0 

    return nodeTable

currentNode = startNode

#find the nearest neighbour to a particular node
def nearestNeighbour(currentNode, theNetwork):
     listOfNeighbours = []
     nodeIndex = 0
     for networkNode in theNetwork[currentNode]:
          if networkNode != 0 and nodeTable[nodeIndex].visited == False:
            listOfNeighbours.append(networkNode)
            nodeIndex +=1
     print "The nearest neighbours are", listOfNeighbours
##     #print node.distFromSource, node.previous, node.visited
##
     return listOfNeighbours

def tentativeDistance (theNetwork, listOfNeighbours):
    shortestPath = []
    for nodeIndex in theNetwork:
         currentDistance = listOfNeighbours[nodeIndex] + startNode
         print currentDistance
         if currentDistance[theNetwork][nodeIndex] < Node.distFromSource:
            theNetwork[node].previous = nodeIndex
            theNetwork[node].distFromSource = nodeIndex
            theNetwork[node].visited = True;
            shortestPath.append(indexNode)
            nodeIndex +=1
    print shortestPath

if __name__ == "__main__":
     nodeTable = populateNodeTable()
    #nodeTable = populateNodeTable(self)
     theNetwork = network()
     #listOfNeighbours = nearestNeighbour(currentNode, theNetwork)
     #tentativeDistance(theNetwork, listOfNeighbours)
```

The output of my network function is a 2D list:

```
[[0, 2, 4, 1, 6, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0], [6, 5, 0, 1, 0, 5, 5], [0, 0, 5, 1, 5, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0]]
```

The output of my populateNodeTable function is:

```
The previous node is  -1
The distance from source is  1000000
The previous node is  -1
The distance from source is  1000000
The previous node is  -1
The distance from source is  1000000
The previous node is  -1
The distance from source is  1000000
The previous node is  -1
The distance from source is  1000000
The previous node is  -1
The distance from source is  1000000
The previous node is  -1
The distance from source is  1000000
```

My network text file has this format (minus the line spacing):

0,2,4,1,6,0,0

2,0,0,0,5,0,0

4,0,0,0,5,5,0

1,0,0,0,1,1,0

6,5,0,1,0,5,5

0,0,5,1,5,0,0

0,0,0,0,5,0,0

The error is:

```
currentDistance = listOfNeighbours[nodeIndex] + startNode
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list
```

This is the contents of my listOfNeighbours, generated in another of my functions:

```
[2, 4, 1, 6]
```

I don't understand the Python documentation on this, doesn't really make it sound easy for a beginner

Comment: What are the contents of theNetwork? Is it a list of lists?

Comment: And what `theNetwork` is ? The problem seems to be there...

Comment: what is the content of `theNetwork` ? I think the error is clear it say that indice of the list `listOfNeighbours` that you give is a list not an integer so `nodeIndex` is a list.

Answer (score 4):

```
for nodeIndex in theNetwork:
```

does not make `nodeIndex` iterate over *indices* in `theNetwork`, but over the *values* of its elements. You should use

```
for nodeIndex,node in enumerate(theNetwork):
    # theNetwork[nodeIndex] is now known as node
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your theNetwork variable by printing it at your console:

```
print(theNetwork)
```

It could be a list of lists, and what you are wanting it to be (in order to use its individual items as indicies) is for it to be a list of ints.

Comment: How can I post the rest of my code without causing confusion for other people?

Comment: You can try to edit your code and make it more concise, by that I mean it should contain at least descriptions of what each variable types are. Typically with more context, people can help you better. The second step is to just try to provide more details when asked :-)

Comment: OK, i've included everything in my post now

Comment: So what does print(theNetWork) tell you? If you see it's something like: [[1,3],[4,5],...,] then that's the problem. You want theNetwork to be a list of integers, such as [1,2,3,4], so you can use it's values as index to access the other list.

Comment: print theNetwork gives a 2D list, [[0, 2, 4, 1, 6, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0], [6, 5, 0, 1, 0, 5, 5], [0, 0, 5, 1, 5, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0]]

Comment: I would check @phihag's answer, and if that doesn't help you will need to rethink the way you want to access listOfNeighbours values. Basically right now theNetwork is a list of lists, you can't use a list as an index to another array.

Answer (score 0):

listOfNeighbors is a list, indexed from zero. So, listOfNeighbors[0] = 2, listOfNeighbors[1] = 4. The error is telling you that nodeIndex, which you're using as indices to access the items in listOfNeighbors, is a list -- not an integer value as expected. Which means that theNetwork must be comprised of lists. You can try a "print nodeIndex" prior to assigning a value to currentDistance to see what it's comprised of. Also, I don't see where you define "node" or "indexNode" in the above function, either.

Also, just to clarify -- is this a function you will ultimately pass to map? I don't see a map call anywhere in the function.

Comment: I've typed in 'print nodeIndex' above 'currentDistance =' but says that the global name 'node index' is not defined. The intention is to look at the list of neighbours, which should be comprised of ints, and work out the distance from source, and I think map is best used for this as it's a list at the moment

Comment: @user612041: If you typed `print nodeIndex`, the error message would **NOT** complain about `node index`. Try typing the correct name, and report back exactly what happened -- use copy/paste, don't type from memory. You don't have a problem with the `map` function, you haven't even used it, so don't include it in your question title.